# Conversion issue

Tags: c#, type-conversion, parameter-passing

See the below lines,

```
private int task
{
  get { return int.Parse(TaskText.Text); }
  set { TaskText.Text = value.ToString(); }
}
```

I want to pass this to some constructor as an int parameter, but I want it should contain string value.

Comment: You wrote a statement, not a question.

Comment: And there is no "above line", but there are several "below".

Comment: It's impossible to store a string value in an int parameter

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
//MAKE PROPERTY STRING 
private string task 
{ 
     get { return TaskText.Text; } 
     set { TaskText.Text = value; } 
}
```

and before passing to ctor :

```
int parameterForCtor = int.Parse(task ); 

//CALL CTOR
```

Comment: Well, if `TaskText.Text` is not a valid representation of an `int`, then it is impossible. What is the value of `TaskText.Text` at the point you want to use it as a parameter for the constructor?

Comment: It's string. but I want it to be int for passing to parameter only.

Comment: That is not possible. You need to change the constructor to take a string as a parameter instead of an int. What are you trying to do?